# Save a PySpark dataframe in a SQL database in Synapse gives the error "IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm"

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I tried to save a PySpark dataframe in a SQL database in Synapse:

```
test = spark.createDataFrame([Row("Sarah", 28), Row("Anne", 5)], ["Name", "Age"])
test.write\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=azlsynddap001;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated")\
    .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")\
    .option("dbTable", "test_CP")\
    .save()
```

I got the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm
```

Here is the detail of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7675/2619697817.py in <module>
      1 test = spark.createDataFrame([Row("Sarah", 28), Row("Anne", 5)], ["Name", "Age"])
----> 2 test.write\
      3     .format("jdbc")\
      4     .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=XXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated")\
      5     .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")\

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1105             self.format(format)
   1106         if path is None:
-> 1107             self._jwrite.save()
   1108         else:
   1109             self._jwrite.save(path)

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116                 # JVM exception message.
--> 117                 raise converted from None
    118             else:
    119                 raise

IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm
```

Where does this error come from? I googled everywhere but no way to find what I did wrong. I also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69753655/spark-read-gives-krbexception-in-databricks) has the same problem as me.

Comment: Can you try using dedicated synapse connector instead of jdbc details here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export

Comment: I have added it as answer , Please upvote/accept it if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using a dedicated synapse connector instead of JDBC, more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala%2Cscala1%2Cscala2%2Cscala3%2Cscala4%2Cscala5)

Also if you are using databricks then you can try using databricks SQL DW connector details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#--authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my environment, I solved like this.

**Sample Data frame**

```
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("aa", "20"), ("bb", "10"), ("jk", "30")]
```

**Sample code**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.jdbc('jdbc:sqlserver://<SQL_server>.database.windows.net:1433;database=vamsi', 'Table_name',
                  mode='overwrite',
                  properties={'user': 'User_name', 'password': 'User_password'})
```

[image: Ref1]

**Output:**

[image: Ref3]